# Getting a NoSuchMethodError in Dart

Tags: dart, nosuchmethoderror

I'm pretty new to Dart, and I'm used to working with C# (and XNA usually), so Dart is a little different, and I'm not sure why this error is happening.

```dart
double left = c.Position.x - (canvasDimensions.x * 0.5);
```

the Position and canvasDimensions are a type I created, called Vector2, which basically contains 2 numbers, x and y, I am getting the error

```dart
NoSuchMethodError : method not found: '-'
Receiver: null
Arguments: [600.0]
```

on the line shown, since I am not familiar with the language I am not sure why this is happening, please help, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `c.Position.x` is `null`. In Dart calling a method (or an operator `-` in your case) on `null` leads to a `NoSuchMethodError`.

Comment: Thanks, that will be very useful to know in future, I hope they do change that though, it is very misleading!

Comment: Misleading in what sense? `null` is an ordinary object in Dart, like all others. If you try to call a method on an object that doesn't have it, you get `NoSuchMethodError` with all the details -- the name of the method, the object that you are calling the method on (receiver) and all the arguments.